# virtuemart where are store product options in DB

Tags: mysql, magento, joomla, e-commerce, virtuemart

I have a problem with virtumart ... i dont know in which table of mysql DB are store information about product options
like this

[there are 4 different options to choice](http://www.patriasport.com/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=productdetails&virtuemart_product_id=2313&virtuemart_category_id=9&Itemid=100213)

i search in a lot of table in DB but i dont found it :(

```
ptr_virtuemart_products
ptr_virtuemart_products_it_it
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the options are saved in fields with json specifications. You can run a dump and search for the string you are looking in the created sql file.

Answer (score 0):

table called: _virtuemart_product_customfields in your case ptr_virtuemart_product_customfields and stores all custom fields.